# How to write an authorization level function in C#?

Tags: c#, azure-functions

Below is the code required to run an Azure function.

Is there anyways I can make it cleaner and compact?

My main issue is with the first parameter.

```
public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
    ILogger log)     {
    // Implementation omitted     }
```

Answer (score 0):

@ASKYous,

This is already the refactored code which comes bu default with the template.

```
public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
    ILogger log)
{
    // Implementation omitted
}
```

with only 2 Parameter:

- Httprequest
- ILogger

You can use something like below if you don't want authorization part:

using System.Net;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

```
public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

    string name = req.Query["name"];

    string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
    dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
    name = name ?? data?.name;

    return name != null
        ? (ActionResult)new OkObjectResult($"Hello, {name}")
        : new BadRequestObjectResult("Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body");
}
```

Also You can bind to a custom object instead of HttpRequest. This object is created from the body of the request and parsed as JSON. Similarly, a type can be passed to the HTTP response output binding and returned as the response body, along with a 200 status code.

```
using System.Net;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

public static string Run(Person person, ILogger log)
{   
    return person.Name != null
        ? (ActionResult)new OkObjectResult($"Hello, {person.Name}")
        : new BadRequestObjectResult("Please pass an instance of Person.");
}

public class Person {
     public string Name {get; set;}
}
```